# How to integrate Dancer2::Core::HTTP helpers for rendering HTTP status codes?

Tags: perl, dancer2

Dancer2 is a PSGI web application framework, we can use the "plackup" tool (provided by Plack) for launching the application:

```
plackup -p 5000 bin/app.psgi
```

The web application created using Dancer2 script can be viewed on localhost and port 5000.

```
http://localhost:5000
```

We can then write a get request as follows:

```
get '/hello/:name' => sub {
               return "Hi there " . route_parameters->get('name');
           };
```

For GET requests to "/hello/...", the code block provided above gets executed.

If the application is down, for GET requests to "/hello/...", the following error is shown:

```
curl: (7) Failed connect to localhost:5000; Connection refused
```

How do we integrate Dancer2::Core::HTTP helpers for rendering HTTP status codes for Dancer2 so that the following status code is shown when the app is down?  Similarly, there are other error handlers too, how to integrate them as well?

```
status_500    status_error, status_internal_server_error
```

Comment: What does _when the app is down_ mean?

Comment: The web server/application can't return error codes if the web server/application isn't running. `curl` is returning a network communication error because it can't connect to the web service at all.